# How can I manipulate extended attributes with PHP?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, xattr

So I have a huge list of text files inside a folder that I must process using a PHP script, and if processing is successful, I need to discard the file. However I only want to attempt  3 times each file, at most. If after the 3rd attempt it fails, I'll discard the file regardless.

So after doing some research I learned about Linux extended file attributes, and that seemed to be a viable way of keeping a counter in each file by means of an extended attribute.

Further research told me PHP supports this with a Pear package named xattr. I then installed the required libattr extension by running this command line (This is an Ubuntu 12.04 system by the way):

```
sudo apt-get install libattr1-dev
```

That worked fine. I then installed Pear xattr with:

```
sudo pecl -v install xattr
```

Which also succeeded and it indicated I had to add this line to php.ini:

```
extension=xattr.so
```

Which I also did and then restarted Apache. But when I attempted to use any of the xattr commands in PHP I always get this:

> Call to undefined function xattr_supported()...

I checked `phpinfo()` and it indicates xattr support is enabled....

So what am I missing here? Shouldn't xattr_supported() at least return a boolean indicating whether extended attributes are supported by the file system or not? Or, is there any other way I can write random data to a plain text file without altering its contents?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ubuntu uses multiple php.ini files, depending on its environment (one for apache, one for the cli, one for cgi, one for fpm, etc.). Make sure you edited the file in `/etc/php5/apache2`.